# MySql: Multiple Left Joins makes query really slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Running the following query takes forever. All the tables contain more than 200,000 records. Indexes exist on all the columns in the joining statements:

```
Select files.filename,
coalesce(temp_decmetadata.glare_roadGlare, 0) as glare_roadGlare,
coalesce(temp_decmetadata.glare_sun, 0) as glare_sun,
coalesce(temp_decmetadata.spray_heavySpray, 0) as spray_heavySpray,
coalesce(temp_kafaspdobjectdata.contrast_wellVisible, 0) as contrast_wellVisible,
coalesce(temp_kafaspdobjectdata.roadSafety_zebraCrossing, 0) as roadSafety_zebraCrossing,
coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadUser_bicycle, 0) as roadUser_bicycle,
coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadUser_car, 0) as roadUser_car,
coalesce(temp_visionmetadata.roadUser_pedestrian, 0) as roadUser_pedestrian
from files
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when glare like '%roadGlare%' then 1 end) as glare_roadGlare,
 count(case when glare like '%sun%' then 1 end) as glare_sun,
 count(case when spray like '%heavySpray%' then 1 end) as spray_heavySpray
 from decmetadata
 group by id 
) temp_decmetadata on temp_decmetadata.id = files.id 
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when contrast like '%wellVisible%' then 1 end) as contrast_wellVisible,
 count(case when roadSafety like '%zebraCrossing%' then 1 end) as roadSafety_zebraCrossing
 from kafaspdobjectdata
 group by id 
) temp_kafaspdobjectdata on temp_kafaspdobjectdata.id = files.id 
left join 
(
 Select id,
 count(case when roadUser like '%bicycle%' then 1 end) as roadUser_bicycle,
 count(case when roadUser like '%car%' then 1 end) as roadUser_car,
 count(case when roadUser like '%pedestrian%' then 1 end) as roadUser_pedestrian
 from visionmetadata
 group by id 
) temp_visionmetadata on temp_visionmetadata.id = files.id
```

Result of "Explain Select..." is attached below:

[image: Explain Select...]

Comment: You say that there are indexes, but your EXPLAIN SELECT suggests otherwise - there are no possible_keys and Extra doesn't show it using any keys... you might want to check your indexes?

Comment: You don't have 'using where' in any of those extra columns, and it looks like you are just selecting all 277758 files with extra bits attached. This will not be quick, whatever you do. How long does the select take on just the files table with no joins?

Comment: Files takes approximately 1 second, and yes WHERE clause is intentionally left out, need to search from the whole database @ Matt Gibson

Comment: @amaidment: Tables other than Files don't have any primary key of their own, but have foreign key ID from Files table and that ID column is indexed in all the tables including Files.

Comment: Any help/ideas/suggestions will be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MySQL specialist, but you can sure improve the sub-queries by moving the JOIN condition to the inner `WHERE` conditions and filtering the rows to only those that satisfies any `CASE` condition, this will decrease the number of rows that must be evaluated by the `LIKE` operator (this is the most expensive operation in this query). The following script should give you the idea:

```
...
CROSS JOIN  (
  SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN glare LIKE '%roadGlare%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS glare_roadGlare,
  SUM(CASE WHEN glare LIKE '%sun%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS glare_sun,
  SUM(CASE WHEN spray LIKE '%heavySpray%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS spray_heavySpray
  FROM decmetadata
  WHERE ( id = files.id ) -- benefits from an index over DECMETADATA.ID
    AND ( 1=2
      OR glare LIKE '%roadGlare%'
      OR glare LIKE '%sun%'
      OR spray LIKE '%heavySpray%'
    )
) temp_decmetadata
...
```

Comment: It didn't work, plus it makes the query so complex as there can be more than 3 Joins and several columns!

Comment: Hi, @sunsa428, the main goal in my suggestion was to reduce the amount of data each sub-query must process to calculate the resulting columns you are actually using, and I still think it could lead to a performance gain (the other was to use a full-text based search instead of using `LIKE`). Can you provide the table structures, so I can make further tests and build the entire query on sqlfiddle?

Comment: Files table has ID as primary key which is also the foreign key to all other tables. Files table has one-to-many relationship with other tables.
Indexes exist in all the tables on thier ID (foreign key).

Comment: If you've created foreign keys, I assume you're using InnoDB, thus the primary key already sorts the table on the ID columns -- that would be one of my suggestions... For what I can see, there are two ways to improve response time: implement a full-text search over the searched columns or move the `files.id` into each sub-query to reduce the amount of data read in each interaction. The first suggestion probably will result in a better overall time, the second suggestion can return the firs rows faster (in UI, this is almost always preferable).

Comment: (continuing) These two suggestions are not exclusive, but if you provide the number of rows of each table I could tell you which alternative **probably** yields a better improvement. If you provide the structure of the tables I can check the full query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is well-structured. The issue is all of the `like '%xxx%'` queries. Indexes will not help those clauses when you are substring matching like that.

Try using [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Comment: But when I execute the sub-queries separately (one by one) then they run perfect.